# How to perform a boolean search using the Twitter search API through tweepy

Tags: twitter, tweepy, data-science

```
new_tweets = api.search(q=searchQuery, count=tweetsPerQry)
```

How do i perform a AND , OR, NOT serach for **searchQuery** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tweepy's `api.search` method send the `q` parameter directly to [Standard search API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets) (`/search/tweets.json`) of Twitter's REST API endpoint.

So you can check which parameter can be accepted by this endpoint in "Standard search operators" section of this document:

- [Using standard search — Twitter Developers](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/guides/standard-operators)

Therefore, we can search tweets including `stackoverflow` about `python` or `ruby` without `tweepy` by using the search query like this: `"stackoverflow (python OR ruby) -tweepy"`.

Basically, these search operators are just the same as ones we can use in the Twitter's official search textbox.

Comment: Is it possible to do a NOT search using the streaming API. For example, query=["aids","hiv"] gives me aids OR hiv and query=["aids hiv"] gives aids AND hiv. But, what do we do for NOT ?

Answer (score 2):

- AND is the default. e.g. query = "big data" is "big" and "data" in the tweet.
- OR is done by using OR operator. e.g. query = "like OR love"
- Negation is done using "-" symbol. e.g. query = "apple -phone"

More details here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/guides/standard-operators.html